# when Class newInstance is called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created One Android app using fragment layout. I faced an issue of "**empty constructor**" So I have Change my code.

```
public static final GridFragment newInstance(Item[] gridItems)
 {
     GridFragment f = new GridFragment();
     Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
     bdl.putParcelableArray("objitem", gridItems);
     f.setArguments(bdl);
     return f;
 }
```

**GridFragment**  is extends **SherlockFragment** and I used it with **HomeActivity** which extends **SherlockFragmentActivity**
In HomeActivity I have used **onResume()** And I added code which binds all stuff for fragment. Now my problem is this 
**Error**

```
******** CAUSE OF ERROR ********
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pavans.converter/com.pavans.converter.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to com.pavans.converter.model.Item[]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to com.pavans.converter.model.Item[]
at com.pavans.converter.GridFragment.onCreateView(GridFragment.java:55)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4489)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2050)
... 11 more

It occurs some time when memory is slow I mean when app goes with wait mode. I guess reason is low memory.  But my confusion is this when I try to press menu button and send app to background and reopen it mean it goes in resume mode. It works fine than Why fragment become empty? I mean is it not goes with resume method of an activity class? My item class is implements Parcelable
Fragment onCreateView

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
     gridItems= (Item[])  bundle.getParcelableArray("objitem");// line no 55
  View view;
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, container, false);
  mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
  return view;
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure this error occurs when you put the items into the bundle? Because it seems that you get the error while reading from the bundle in your fragment.

Comment: @SteveBenett thanks for replay, I got this error Only when memory is low I mean this error only occures, when empty constructor occured

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of the error? If it's about low memory the static factory method isn't the reason for the error. Because the system will not call it, but the empty constructor.

Comment: OK, now please show the line 55, if it's part of a block show it completely.

Comment: @SteveBenett My full code is some thing like this http://shrikantsonarblogs.blogspot.in/2013/07/gridview-with-viewpager-like-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to iterate through `Parcelable[]` and then cast items to `Item` one by one?

```
items = bundle.getParcelableArray("objitem");
for (Parcelable item : items) {
    mItem = (Item) item;
}
```

Because you may be not able to cast parcelable array directly.

Actually I would prefer to write a setData() method in Fragment class and set array later. Or maybe I would write a getter in activity for items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have clearly mentioned that when empty constructor fragment occurs than only error occured..